# QGIS merged raster files displays stitching line

Tags: qgis, merge

I am merging three raster files - essentially three satellite images. I am using QGIS's tool merge (raster -> miscellaneous -> merge). In the merge box, I've tried ticking "grab pseudocolor table from first layer" and also without it.

See screenshot below:

[image]